# Query to get number of running stock for each item_id on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0 which already support windowed function. 
Given current dataset like on image below
[data set with 2 kind of item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7mnS.png)

I need to get stock position on each stock movement. 
With query like below

```
> SELECT h.item, h.item_date, h.item_qty, h.item_flow,
> @stock := @stock + (h.item_qty*h.item_flow) AS running_stock FROM stock h CROSS JOIN (SELECT @stock := 0) r  WHERE h.item = 1 ORDER
> BY h.item
```

I can get running stock for specific item

[result with running stock for each date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVCj1.png)

My Question is :
***How can I modify my query so I can get result for all kind of item within a single query? 
I don't know how to reset @stock variable on each group.***

Adding column is not a solution as I need to solve this within a query. Adding a column would require me to calculate each time new stock movement added in-between date (there will be a back-date transaction)

[Expected result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5DFi.png)

Comment: sorry for being unclear, the data should be ordered by item column, then sorted by date and item_flow.. so each item in on each day would be counted first before they taken out. .the order should be ORDER BY item, item_date, item_flow DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    item,
    item_date,
    item_qty,
    item_flow,
    SUM(item_qty*item_flow) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item_date) AS running_stock
FROM stock
ORDER BY
    item,
    item_date;
```

Comment: So that kind of [gives the correct result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c71d2e3678c840c61dc16c1308a1d56b) except there are two stock movements on the same day so it doesn't quite match. But without an `id` or something to order by there's no way to improve on it.

Comment: @Nick Maybe that apparent date column actually has a time component which isn't being shown.

Comment: Well, then it will work perfectly and absolutely justifies the upvote I already gave it! :-)

Comment: ah sorry, the order should be by date and flow.. so on same day, any stock in  would be counted first then out

Comment: well this work too! weird since I have try to use OVER before but the result is not correct. LoL.. I think I missed the correct order here. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score -1):

Got working query.. referenced from [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/)

```
> SELECT h.item, h.item_date, h.item_qty, h.item_flow,
>      @stock :=CASE WHEN @item_id=h.item THEN @stock + (h.item_qty*h.item_flow) ELSE h.item_qty * h.item_flow END AS
> running_stock,
>      @item_id:=h.item AS item_id FROM stock h CROSS JOIN (SELECT @stock := 0, @item_id := '') r  ORDER BY h.item, h.item_date,
> h.item_flow DESC
```

give me expected results as I expected. The most crucial key is to reset @stock value to default (`item_qty * item_flow`) each time `item` column value change

Comment: scratch this, I prefer solution using OVER (PARTITION BY ... ) above as it is more neat! This kind of query might come handy though in other time